# Using JsonComponent with RabbitListener

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit, jackson-databind

I am trying to use a custom deserializer:

```
@JsonComponent
class SuffixDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {

    private final String suffix;

    SuffixDeserializer(@Value("${suffix}") String suffix) {
        this.suffix = suffix;
    }

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser json, DeserializationContext ctx) 
            throws IOException {
        return json.getText() + suffix;
    }
}
```

for a RabbitMQ listener:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
class FooListener {

    @RabbitListener(queuesToDeclare = @Queue(name = "foo", durable = "true"))
    void foo(Message msg) {
        log.info("Received {}", msg);
    }

    @Data
    static class Message {
        @JsonDeserialize(using = SuffixDeserializer.class)
        private String field;
    }
}
```

I even tried to register `JsonComponentModule` explicitly:

```
@Bean
public MessageConverter jsonConverter() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
            .registerModule(new JsonComponentModule());
    return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter(mapper);
}
```

But when I run this code, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Class io.github.jjarzynski.jsoncomponentmq.SuffixDeserializer has no default (no arg) constructor
 at [Source: (String)"{"field": "bar"}"; line: 1, column: 1]
```

Which implies that Jackson is trying to create its own instance rather than use the Spring Bean.

**How do I apply a custom Spring Bean deserializer to a field in incoming RabbitMQ messages?**

Answer (score 0):

The exception is cleary stating that:

> SuffixDeserializer has no default (no arg) constructor at [Source:
> (String)"{"field": "bar"}"; line: 1, column: 1]

So you need to put a default constructor on suffixDeserializer class, and probably also getters and setters to set the suffix.

```
@JsonComponent
class SuffixDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {

    private String suffix;

    SuffixDeserializer() {}

    SuffixDeserializer(@Value("suffix") String suffix) {
        this.suffix = suffix;
    }

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser json, DeserializationContext ctx) 
            throws IOException {
        return json.getText() + suffix;
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding a no arg constructor and changing constructor dependency injection to setter dependency injection doesn't solve the issue. I end up with null suffix value. Jackson is instantiating its own SuffixDeserializer independent of the Spring Bean.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have been able to use the `SuffixDeserializer` bean is by registering it in the following way:

```
@Bean
MessageConverter jsonConverter(SuffixDeserializer deserializer) {

    SimpleModule jsonComponentModule = new JsonComponentModule()
            .addDeserializer(String.class, deserializer);

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
            .registerModule(jsonComponentModule);

    return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter(mapper);
}
```

Which suggests that the `@JsonComponent` scan is of no use with RabbitMQ? I might as well annotate `SuffixDeserializer` with `@Component`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I just spent a couple hours debugging the issue of JsonComponentsModule not pulling in the deserializers and finally figured it out.

The problem is how you're registering the module. If you look at the `JsonComponentModule` class you'll see that it uses the following

```
@Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        registerJsonComponents();
    }

    public void registerJsonComponents() {
        BeanFactory beanFactory = this.beanFactory;
        while (beanFactory != null) {
            if (beanFactory instanceof ListableBeanFactory listableBeanFactory) {
                addJsonBeans(listableBeanFactory);
            }
            beanFactory = (beanFactory instanceof HierarchicalBeanFactory hierarchicalBeanFactory)
                    ? hierarchicalBeanFactory.getParentBeanFactory() : null;
        }
    }
```

This is when it creates the deserializers. This so happens to occur after the bean is configured, so creating a `new JsonComponentModule()` breaks this. It never wires in the beans.

In order to make this work you there's two options. If Spring is using Jackson auto configuration then you need to autowire in the already configured `JsonComponentModule` bean provided by spring e.g.

```
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper(JsonComponentModule jsonComponentModule){
        return new ObjectMapper()
            .registerModule(jsonComponentModule);
    }
```

If not, then you will first need to create the `JsonComponentModule` bean. e.g.

```
    @Bean
    public JsonComponentModule jsonComponentModule(){
        return new JsonComponentModule();
    }
```

And then autowire that into your object mapper creation.